# apple push notification service using php

Tags: php, iphone

I used the following code for getting push notification. but i am getting an error like           **Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to  ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in D:\xampp\htdocs\push_test\push_test.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 5 Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?**
i dont know what to do. please help..

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'xxxxxxxxx';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',      'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows that you haven't enabled OpenSSL support on your server, check that and let me know.

Comment: how could i know whether OpenSSL support si enabled or disabled. and i am running my code on my pc.. so how could i know whether its enabled or disabled.. if its in the phpifo(); then its like this: 
OpenSSL support disabled (install ext/openssl)

Comment: The line 'OpenSSL support disabled (install ext/openssl)' says that your ssl support is disabled.

Here is how to solve it:

Start your server and look for 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path' and 'Loaded Configuration File' in your phpinfo

Open Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\WINDOWS, find ;extension=php_openssl.dll and delete the semicolon

Open Loaded Configuration File C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add this code extension=php_openssl.dll in the extension section.

Comment: i have two php.ini file.. one is for ini production and other for ini development.. so where should i change it.. thanss for the help..

Comment: Change the php.ini file located in `D:\xampp\php\` (as per your system), i guess there will be only one php.ini file and that's the target.